# YQL Commercial Use

Tags: yql

Yahoo YQL states that their service can be used for commercial use, if approved. However, there is no contact information anywhere. The only thing they reference is to use #YQL on stackoverflow. So here is my question, where do I go and who do I contact to possibly use YQL for commercial use?

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/

```
Can I use YQL for commercial projects?
Absolutely! We'd love you to use YQL for all your projects. However, we cannot give you extra permissions to the APIs you use through YQL. For example, if you access Flickr through YQL you will still need to use a Flickr commercial API key for commercial projects.
```

Comment: That's not what it says on the license page.

Comment: What does it say there... I've read most everything I can find. I'm most interested in the Fantasy API. The terms are here https://developer.yahoo.com/terms/. Says you shall NOT use or provision of the Yahoo! APIs, whether for direct commercial or monetary gain or otherwise, without Yahoo!'s prior, express, written permission; or

Comment: YQL itself grabs data from other things. You can use YQL for commercially, however the data it gets are licensed under their own terms.

Answer (score 1):

Those extra permissions they are talking about are from flickr, or twitter, or whoever you trying to access. You need to already have the API keys to talk to those services. The YQL part is free to use wherever you can